# Why doesn't vagrant password work on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, vagrant

I am installing `vagrant`(version `1.7.2`) on `Windows 7`. During `vagrant up` process, I add`config.ssh.insert_key = false` according to `vagrant` prompt. Then I use the following `SSH` command to login:

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
Password:
```

I input `vagrant`, but can't login. Could anyone give any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause is forgetting using private key.

For `putty` client,  please refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885108/ssh-to-vagrant-box-in-windows

For `Cygwin` client:

```
Copy C:\Users\user_name\.vagrant.d\insecure_private_key to Cygwin's  /home/user_name/.ssh/id_rsa
```